# How to use output of FFMPEG as command line argument to an executable

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, stdout

I have a .wmv file which I want to convert to .wav file and I am using ffmpeg for the same, the command is as follows:

```
ffmpeg -i file.wmv -ar 8000 -sample_fmt s16 -f wav pipe:1
```

the pipe:1 outputs the output wave file in STDOUT. I want to capture that wave file from STDOUT and pass it as a command line argument to my executable called foo. I want to do the conversion from wmv to wav on the fly rather than saving the .wav file.
Things I have tried are as follows but none of them seem to work:

```
./foo $(ffmpeg -i file.wmv -ar 8000 -sample_fmt s16 -f wav pipe:1)

./foo $(<(ffmpeg -i file.wmv -ar 8000 -sample_fmt s16 -f wav pipe:1))

ffmpeg -i file.wmv -ar 8000 -sample_fmt s16 -f wav pipe:1 | xargs ./foo

ffmpeg -i file.wmv -ar 8000 -sample_fmt s16 -f wav - | ./foo -
```

Comment: Why not just pipe it and have your program read from stdin?

Comment: The design of the executable is not in my control

Comment: What about using bash process redirection?  Your second example, but with just `<(ffmpeg ...)`, and not the `$(` and `)` ? The result of that would look something like `./foo /dev/fd/63`, where the fd was populated by the output of the command.

Comment: Oh, I was too slow, chepner already got it.

Comment: `ffmpeg -i file.wmv -ar 8000 -sample_fmt s16 -f wav - | ./foo /dev/stdin` is another option, subject to most of the caveats relevant to process substitution (FIFO, non-seekable, &c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your second attempt is close:

```
./foo <(ffmpeg ...)
```

The process substitution expands to a name, which `foo` can open like any other file. The contents of this "file" are the output from `ffmpeg`.

Note, however, this will not work if `foo` expects a seekable file; the output of `ffmpeg` is still a stream which is not buffered in memory. If `foo` expects to be able to move back and forth through the file, you need to use an actual file. (`ffmpeg ... > tmp; ./foo tmp`)

---

In the first case, you are trying to pass the *contents* of the output stream as an argument, similar to `./foo "$(cat some.mp4)"`.

In the third case, you are treating the output of `ffmpeg` as the *name* of a file.

The fourth case would work if `foo` were written to understand `-` as a stand-in name for standard input. That is a program convention, not something provided by the shell.

Comment: Thanks. but I am little confused as to how the <(ffmpeg ...) syntax serves as a command line argument as opposed to stdin.

Comment: Process substitution is, in some sense, a way of creating a temporary file. Try `echo <(:)` (`:` being the do-nothing command). The output is the name of the "file" that the process substitution creates.